# Converting numerical categories to text label in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, labeling, expression, text

In QGIS I have a smallish dataset with around 8k cells in. Each cell has a number of attributes including a code for land surface cover (an integer between 0 and 12). I have a list of labels that go with each code, and I want to add these labels as a new column to the attributes table.

This problem sounds a lot like something that's reasonably common, but I can't find a solution anywhere. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) to create a new field with the following expression, using a [case](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-contains) statement. You can add as many `when` conditions as you like:

```
case 
    when "areacode" = 1 then 'one' 
    when "areacode" = 2 then 'two'
end
```

For all other cases (e.g. you defined areacodes 0 to 12, and now want to define a result for values like `NULL`, `13` etc.) `else ''` in the line after the last when condition and before the `end` to get an empty output.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing it would be to define a lookup table - a table with two columns areacode (int) and label (varchar). Then you fill in the table:

```
areacode | label
       1 | One areacode
       2 | Another areacode
```

and so on. When the table is complete, you can join it with your initial coverage.